# AspNet Identity Framework writing to master database on SQL Azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, azure, azure-sql-database, asp.net-identity

I'm running into an issue when trying to deploy a simple MVC website to Azure. I am using 1 azure website and 1 Azure SQL database.

The boilerplate MVC template in VS2013 uses the `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework` provider for the `AccountController.cs` default controller. When I use this to create the database locally, everything works just fine. However, when I deploy to Azure Websites and update the connection string, the site throws this error:

`Cannot open database "master" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'vanillawebsite'.`

See full stack trace here: http://pastebin.com/r9jvXgyW (it's massive)

Obviously, on SQL Azure there's no master database, so the default implementation of AspNet Identity Eneity Framework seems to need it though. Manually scripting out the schema to the database doesn't help either (it still attempts to access master for some reason)

Why is it trying to access master database, and how can I work around this?

Comment: What connection string do you use?

Comment: For what it's worth, SQL Azure does have a master database.

Comment: SQL user you use in your connection string does not have access to your database.

Comment: @trailmax that was it -- I actually had the name of the database wrong. The error message was pretty misleading though. Thanks for the (simple!) advice that led to this solution. If you post this as an answer, I can mark so you get credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said before, SQL Azure has `master` database and usually when you see this message means that SQL user used in connection string does not have a right to access to the DB in question. Or the DB does not exist, i.e. misspelled name.